# Writing a Vec<String> to files using std::fs::write

Tags: rust, io

I'm writing a program that handles a vector which is combination of numbers and letters (hence `Vec<String>`). I sort it with the `.sort()` method and am now trying to write it to a file.

Where `strvec` is my sorted vector that I'm trying to write using `std::fs::write`;

```
println!("Save results to file?");
let to_save: String = read!();
match to_save.as_str() {
    "y" => {
        println!("Enter filename");
        let filename: String = read!();
        let pwd = current_dir().into();
        write("/home/user/dl/results", strvec);
```

Rust tells me "the trait `AsRef<[u8]>` is not implemented for `Vec<String>`". I've also tried using `&strvec`.
How do I avoid this/fix it?

Comment: You have to write each string separately. A list of strings can't be zero-copy-converted to a `u8` slice; each string's data is contiguous, but the string allocations themselves aren't.

Comment: @cdhowie so would I need to iterate through the vector's items, writing them each to the file separately?

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, both of you. @frankenapps no, unfortunately that article does not describe the case of a Vec<String>. Thx tho

Comment: Yes, iterating the vector and doing `write_all` on each is probably the way to go, as that avoids having to merge the strings together (an unnecessary reallocation+copy).

Comment: I've written an answer that explains how you'd do this.

Answer (score 6):

When it comes to writing objects to the file you might want to consider serialization. Most common library for this in Rust is [serde](https://crates.io/crates/serde), however in this example where you want to store vector of Strings and if you don't need anything human readable in file (but it comes with small size :P), you can also use [bincode](https://crates.io/crates/bincode):

```
use std::fs;
use bincode;

fn main() {
    let v = vec![String::from("aaa"), String::from("bbb")];
    let encoded_v = bincode::serialize(&v).expect("Could not encode vector");
    fs::write("file", encoded_v).expect("Could not write file");

    let read_v = fs::read("file").expect("Could not read file");
    let decoded_v: Vec<String> = bincode::deserialize(&read_v).expect("Could not decode vector");

    println!("{:?}", decoded_v);
}
```

Remember to add *bincode = "1.3.3"* under dependencies in Cargo.toml

#EDIT:
Actually you can easily save String to the file so simple join() should do:

```
use std::fs;

fn main() {
    let v = vec![
        String::from("aaa"),
        String::from("bbb"),
        String::from("ccc")];

    fs::write("file", v.join("\n")).expect("");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems super useful, but I need a human readable file for the use case of this software.

Comment: Just edited the answer - you can easly save String to the file so for your need simple join() on vector should do.

Answer (score 1):

Rust can't write anything besides a `&[u8]` to a file. There are too many different ways which data can be interpreted before it gets flattened, so you need to handle all of that ahead of time. For a `Vec<String>`, it's pretty simple, and you can just use [`concat`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.concat) to squish everything down to a single `String`, which can be interpreted as a `&[u8]` because of its [`AsRef<u8>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#impl-AsRef%3C%5Bu8%5D%3E) trait impl.

Another option would be to use [`join`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.join), in case you wanted to add some sort of delimiter between your strings, like a space, comma, or something.

```rust
fn main() {
    let strvec = vec![
        "hello".to_string(),
        "world".to_string(),
    ];

    // "helloworld"
    std::fs::write("/tmp/example", strvec.concat()).expect("failed to write to file");
    // "hello world"
    std::fs::write("/tmp/example", strvec.join(" ")).expect("failed to write to file");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't get a `&[u8]` from a `Vec<String>` without copying since a slice must refer to a contiguous sequence of items.  Each `String` will have its own allocation on the heap somewhere, so while each individual `String` can be converted to a `&[u8]`, you can't convert the whole vector to a single `&[u8]`.

While you can `.collect()` the vector into a single `String` and then get a `&[u8]` from that, this does some unnecessary copying.  Consider instead just iterating the `String`s and writing each one to the file.  With this helper, it's no more complex than using `std::fs::write()`:

```
use std::path::Path;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::Write;

fn write_each(
    path: impl AsRef<Path>,
    items: impl IntoIterator<Item=impl AsRef<[u8]>>,
) -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let mut file = File::create(path)?;
    for i in items {
        file.write_all(i.as_ref())?;
    }
    // Surface any I/O errors that could otherwise be swallowed when
    // the file is closed implicitly by being dropped.
    file.sync_all()
}
```

The bound `impl IntoIterator<Item=impl AsRef<[u8]>>` is satisfied by both `Vec<String>` and by `&Vec<String>`, so you can call this as either `write_each("path/to/output", strvec)` (to consume the vector) or `write_each("path/to/output", &strvec)` (if you need to hold on to the vector for later).